# Jquery .replaceWith not working proper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a jquery code that is preventing a link to go to that link but executing it. The problem i have is that after it executs the script and script is returning data i want to replace it with a new one but with the same class. The replace is doing inside the dom but next time i press that link is not prevening going to that link but the class is the same, here is my code:

```
<script>
$(".recomanda").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var test=$(this);

    var href = $(this).attr('href');


    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {

        if(data.recom==1)
        {
        $(test).replaceWith('<a class="recomanda" href="app/recomanda_produs.php?id=' + data.id + '&recom=' + data.recom + '">Recomandat</a> ');

        }
        if(data.recom==0)
        {
        $(test).replaceWith('<a class="recomanda" href="app/recomanda_produs.php?id=' + data.id + '&recom=' + data.recom + '">Recomanda</a> ');

        }

    });
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
<a class="recomanda" href="app/recomanda_produs.php?id='.$row['ID_Produs'].'&recom=0">Recomanda</a>
```

Comment: I think the problem is the way you attach the event try this

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.recomanda', function() {});

Comment: hmm it's working with body in front, i tried with `$(".recomanda").on('click',function(e){}` and it didn't work, it seems your answer is good, could you add it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

yeah, I ran into that problem too before, it's because when you attach click to recomanda on ready(), but when ajax load, everything in ready() won't fire again, that why you need to attach the event to non-dynamic elements, and let it find it's child selector.

```
$('body').on('click', '.recomanda', function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a `replaceWith` actually you are removing elements that are bound to onclick handler:

> .replaceWith()
>
> Description: Replace each element in the set of matched elements with
>   the provided new content and return the set of elements that was
>   removed.

The main idea is that you handler must be bound to the same element (that is not removed when clicking). 
So instead of using `replaceWith` method use method that modify existing element like this:

```
test.attr('href', blablabla);
```

And this is not a problem, but second time you don't need to use `$` with `test` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event to a parent so that it can be applied to specific children wether they exist now or in the future.

See: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$("body").on("click", ".recomanda", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var test=$(this);
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {
        if(data.recom==1){
            $(test).replaceWith('<a class="recomanda" href="app/recomanda_produs.php?id=' + data.id + '&recom=' + data.recom + '">Recomanda"+((data.recom==1)?"t":"")+"</a> ');
        }
        if(data.recom==0){
            $(test).replaceWith('<a class="recomanda" href="app/recomanda_produs.php?id=' + data.id + '&recom=' + data.recom + '">Recomanda</a> ');
        }
    });
});
```